# How can I call a function defined in another function?

Tags: python

Today I found that I can't find the way to call a function inside another function. Unless I explicitly return it in the main function or using a closure structure. But I'm wondering if there is another way to call it. Or wouldn't it be so wired, python allow me to define functions inside functions, but doesn't allow me to use them later in a simple way!

My code is like this, and I'd like to call b(),c(),d() after define them.

```
def a():
    def b():
        print 'b'
    def c():
        print 'c'
    def d():
        print 'd'
    print 'a'

>>> a()
a
>>> a.b
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'b'
>>> a.b()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Comment: @vamosrafa, I've spend a whole day on figure out how closure works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call those functions from outside the scope of `a`. They are confined to the scope of `a`.

You can think of these functions in exactly the same way as you think of other local names in a function. For instance:

```
def foo():
    bar = 42
```

Just as you cannot refer to your local functions outside the defining scope, you cannot refer to `bar` outside the scope of `foo()`.

Comment: Thank you, I think I neglect the fact that a normal function is under global scope and instinctively think nested function has the same scope. Now I clearly understand this.

Comment: I found an example which is kind of counter this scope issue. def x():    x.count +=1  >>> x.count = 0 >>>x() >>>x.count >>> 1

Comment: why the inside x.count can be retrieved outside the function now? Is it because I assigned an x.count value globally? And once I assigned that value, it moves an inside function attribute into global scope?

Comment: Those are attributes of the object rather than locals